# Assigning to a Row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to edit rows in a `pandas.DataFrame` by dividing each value by the `row.max()`

what is the recommended way to do this?

I tried

```
df.xs('rowlabel') /= df.xs('rowlabel').max()
```

as I'd do on a `numpy` array, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for a single row is:

```
df.ix['rowlabel'] /= df.ix['rowlabel'].max()
```

If you want that done on every row in the dataframe, you can use apply (with axis=1 to select rows instead of columns):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x / x.max(), axis=1)
```